# Disable default email notification templates

Tags: ee2, email, postmaster, system, system-messages

I've installed the **Postmaster** module from Objective HTML and I'm using the **Send system email** hook. When the system sends an email I will receive it twice because the postmaster hook don't override the system functionality entirely... So how to disable the default email notification templates?

Comment: Hmm, that's not right - Postmaster should be ending execution during that hook. I'd hit Justin up @objectivehtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the `End Script` setting is set to `False` in the hook setup screen. This will prevent the default action from occurring so the email is only sent one time.